# React Infinite loop useEffect when a parameter has an array as default

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

It never happened to me befere and I don't know why is this happening.

I have these two components that create a infinite loop in the useEffect of the children component:

```js
function Container(){
  return <div> <Description /> </div>
}

// If I remove "= []" part no infinite loop is created
function Description({list = []}){
  const [dict, setDict] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('this is for the inifinite loop log')
      setDict({}) // also, If a remove this line no infinite loop is created
  }, [list]) 

  return <div>something...</div>
}
```

** EDITED: this code is just the simplification of my problem **

I understand that the default array is created with a different memory pointer every time the component is re-render but then there is no way to put a list as a default prop and at the same time using it as a useEffect param?

Comment: The easiest thing would be to not render the component in the parent component if `list` is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the state of the function component of React changes, the function is called again. And when the state of the function component changes, if the dependence array of `useEffect` also changes, the callback in `useEffect` is called.

When `setDict` is called in the above code, a new instance of the array, which is the default value to be put in the `list`, is created every time, so `useEffect` update callback continues to be called.

So you can use an empty array as the default by using the same array of instances.

```js
const emptyArray = [];
// If I remove "= []" part no infinite loop is created
function Description({list = emptyArray}){
  const [dict, setDict] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('this is for the inifinite loop log')
      setDict({}) // also, If a remove this line no infinite loop is created
  }, [list]) 

  return <div>something...</div>
}
```

---

I don't know what the final purpose you want just by looking at the example code above. I think your code creates a parameter of `setDict` by processing the `list` from your parent component. In general, I think that the parent of `Description` sends only the array or empty array value to the `list` prop. If so, I think it's a better way to cause an error when the array does not come in without supporting the empty array, which is the default of the `list`.

Answer (score 0):

That's most likely because the `list` array is not the same object in memory, and new array is created each render.

If you have a default {} in your `setDict`, you do not need to re-assign it in your `useEffect`.

This may also be due to you not passing in `list` as a prop in your `Container` function through the `Description` component. If you pass that prop through you should alleviate the infinite loop that way as well.